# using sqlite create virtual table using fts3 with unique column dosnot stay unique

Tags: qt, sqlite

im creating (in Qt )

```
QString q = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE playlist USING fts3 ("
                        "from_user , " 
                        "from_id , "
                        "created_time , "
                        "created_time_formated , "
                        "user_id unique )";
```

then execute

```
"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO  play_list (from_user,from_id,created_time,created_time_formated,user_id) SELECT '....','....','.....','....','123'"
```

im using full Full-Text Search so this is way im using VIRTUAL TABLE

if i have another row with user_id == 123 it will still insert the row , why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FTS documentation [states](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_2) that:

> The same applies to any constraints specified along with an FTS column name - they are parsed but not used or recorded by the system in any way.

So the `UNIQUE` constraint is ignored.

You can emulate the constraint by using a trigger on a view (not on the table because triggers are not available on virtual tables), and then by inserting the row on that view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW playlist_view AS SELECT * FROM playlist;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_playlist INSTEAD OF INSERT ON playlist_view
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'column user_id is not unique') FROM playlist 
        WHERE user_id=new.user_id;
    INSERT INTO playlist (from_user, from_id, created_time, 
                          created_time_formated, user_id) 
    VALUES (NEW.from_user, NEW.from_id, NEW.created_time, 
            NEW.created_time_formated, NEW.user_id);
END;

-- And you do the insertion on the view 
INSERT INTO playlist_view (from_user,from_id,created_time,created_time_formated,user_id) SELECT ...;
```

Because `OR IGNORE` won't ignore an explicit `RAISE`, if you want to ignore the error, you have to replace `RAISE(ABORT,...)` by `RAISE(IGNORE)`.

Comment: i do use full text search on the table , all the fields are text type

Comment: @user63898 Then duplicate the user_id in a regular table, and check if  the id exists before inserting in the FTS table (you can automate this with a transaction or a trigger).

Comment: The additional table is not needed after all, you can check if the id is present directly with the trigger.